# Entity Framework listening to SQL Server changes

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api

I'm working on the following scenario:

I have a console up that populates a SQL Server database with some data. I have one more web app that reads the same database and displays the data on a front-end. Both of the applications use Entity Framework to communicate with the database (they have the same connection string).

I wonder how can the web app be notified for any changes that have occurred to the database. Bear in mind that the two applications are not referenced, whatsoever.

Is there event provided by EF that fires when some has changes. In essence, I would like to know when a change has happened, as well as, the nature of that change

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar requirement and I solved it using the EF function:

```
[context].Database.CompatibleWithModel(throwIfNoMetadata: true)
```

It will return if your model matches the underlying database structure using the metadata table.

Note that I was using a **Code First** approach.

The msdn definition is below:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.compatiblewithmodel(v=vs.103).aspx

Edit:

Just found an amazing article with a demonstration:

http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2011/04/08/code-first-what-is-that-edmmetadata-table/

Comment: Oh that's perfect. Thanks a lot. But how would you go about locating the actual change. Like, can you reach the granularity of specific table (or even record) changes.

Comment: I am pretty sure that you can, but whenever I found an incompatible model I just recreated the database or my entities model. So I really don't no how can you see the changes itself.

Comment: Correct if i'm wrong, but i think this CompatibleWithModel will return false if the structure of the model has changed (e.g. a property was added) and not the actual values.

Comment: Sorry, but for me it was implicit that when you meant a database change you were talking about the schema ;/. The best solution to see if **data** has changed is to host a WCF service in your application and call it using the console application.

Comment: Sorry, i should have made it more clear. Thanks a lot, i'll try to follow your advise. Well, in fact, i would expect this to be an easier task. But in case, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

This is not something that is related to EF at all.  EF is just a library that makes SQL calls and maps them to objects.  It has no inside knowledge of the database.  As such, when data changes in one application, another application doesn't know unless they query to see if that data changes (and you're not going to be constantly running queries to know that, it's too impractical).

There are, potentially some ways to do this, such as adding triggers to the database, which then call extended stored procs to send messages to the app, but this is a lot of work to go through, and it can possibly compromise the robustness of the database.

There used to be something called Notification Services, but that was deprecated.  There's now something called SqlDependency objects, which may help you in some cases.. but it all depends on what you're trying to do exactly.

In any event, it's usually easier to find a different way to do what you want.  This is complex topic, and really requires a lot of sql server knowledge.